# mailx sending email to multiple accounts

Tags: bash, shell, ksh, mailx

I am trying to use mailx to send an email via shell script.

```
Message=<HTML><BODY><p>FINISHED</p></BODY></HTML>

Recipients=email1@email.org;email2@email.org
Recipients=$(echo "${Recipients}" | sed "s/;/ /g")
echo "Recipients:  ${Recipients}"

mailx -s "Ingestion Report ${EXT1}. $( echo "\nContent-Type: text/html")" "${Recipients}" < $MESSAGE
```

my problem is I'm trying to change the list delimited by a semi-colon to a space-delimited list because I"m told that is what's needed by mailx.

However, the response is:

```
sh: email2@email.org:  not found
```

what am I doing wrong? thanks.

Comment: There are many syntax error because of incorrect quoting. You are distracting the attention from your actual question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A semicolon is a command separator, so you have to change how you are defining `Recipients` from:

```
Recipients=email1@email.org;email2@email.org
```

To:

```
Recipients="email1@email.org;email2@email.org"
```

Quoting the value prevents the `;` from being interpreted as a command separator.

Alternatively, you can just define `Recipients` correctly in the first place:

```
Recipients="email1@email.org email2@email.org"
```

Or if you don't control that for whatever reason, you can drop the `sed` call and just do:

```
mailx ... ${Recipients/;/ }
```

Comment: But why would you put a semicolon at all in the first place if everything in your code expects a space separator?

Comment: because I'm pulling the email list from a database and injecting it into the code via parameter.  Spaces are bad there.  But  What I have done, is replaced the semi-colon with a comma, and everything snapped into place.  Thanks much!